# Eclipse: No compile errors. Batch: Compile errors

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

When I am coding in Eclipse I don't have errors,
but when I try compiling the code I just made with a batch compiler,
I get these errors:
[image: The Batch Errors]
[image: Eclipse]
[Alert.java](http://pastebin.com/fgbpQsw1)

[AlertHandler.java](http://pastebin.com/A88X0SNK)

[client.java](http://pastebin.com/jDt8Bi6q)

Compiler.bat code

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath src/*.java src/sign/*.java

pause
```

.classpath file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: How is your CLASSPATH set when compiling from the command line?

Comment: I added my compiler.bat code

Comment: javac -d bin -sourcepath src/*.java src/sign/*.java

pause

Comment: Show your project's .classpath file.

Comment: Added the file to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to compile your project you have to

1. create a text file listing all your java files. For example, `compile-list.txt`:

   ```
   src/MyClass1.java
   src/mypackage/MyClass2.java
   ...
   ```
2. Run `javac` specifying source and target version and the file with your classes:

   ```
   javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 -d bin @compile-list.txt
   ```

Specifying `-sourcepath src` would allow `javac` to resolve unlisted (forgotten) classes from the source directory, in case they are needed.

Since this is extremely unhandy process I would recomment to use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

Comment: Please try my updated command. Post the error messages, if it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: Are you on windows or linux/mac?

Comment: In this case you will have to specify all your java files from the `src` directory :(

Comment: That's why I would recommend to use ant or maven.

Comment: I am asking it somewhere else and there I get answers that actually help me :), but thank you tough.

Comment: Could you please add URL to this answers? (Just answer your own question)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546579/javac-fails-to-find-symbol-when-wildcard-is-used-but-works-when-java-file-is-m