# Javac fails to find symbol when wildcard is used, but works when .java file is manually specified

Tags: java, javac

When I compile with this compiler code:

```
@echo off
javac -d bin -sourcepath src/*.java src/sign/*.java src/Alert.java
pause
```

I don't get any errors.
but when i compiler with this code

```
@echo off
javac -d bin -sourcepath src/*.java src/sign/*.java
pause
```

I do get errors
[image: Compiler errors]

the alert.java is the first file

[image: Alert.java]

Comment: have you tried `javac -d classes -sourcepath src src/sign/*.java`?

Comment: why classes? i want to place the compiled files in bin and not in classes.

Comment: `javac -d bin -sourcepath src src/sign/*.java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this one

```
Navigate to src directory  
javac -d ../bin *.java sign/*.java
```

All the required jars and dependencies must be set in class path before compilation or you can use `-classpath` option while compiling.

--EDIT--

**Try this one without `-sourcepath` option**

```
javac -d bin src/*.java src/sign/*.java
```

Comment: That works but i want it in the main directory that's handier.

Answer (score 2):

The -sourcepath option expects a path, and you aren't giving it one.

When you do this

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath src/*.java src/sign/*.java
```

You are only picking up the files in src/sign/, since src/*.java is being evaluated as the source path.

Comment: You are already putting the path on the java files manually, so just remove the -sourcepath option and it should work

Comment: Ok, and how should my code get when i do use -sourcepath?
that's so i know when to use it and when not ok?